# Linux: run an application fullscreen (not in a window)

Tags: linux, x11

I want to run a program in linux without the X borders. It's a C++ program that uses a graphical library called GRX and when it is launched it runs inside a window.

Is there any way to "force" an app not to run in windowed mode? An exec, comand or something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different domains where you can decide if your application runs in fullscreen mode or not.

1) The "X-Borders" are drawn by your window manager. An application running on your X-Server without a window manager won't have any borders. If theres a fullscreen mode for the application depends on the window manager itself.

For example in my i3 you can use the key combination ALT + F to switch to fullscreen mode.

2) The used graphic driver behind your library.

GRX supports different drivers and you can set them with the following function:

```
     int GrSetDriver(char *drvspec);
```

The SDL driver supports a windowed mode and a fullscreen mode.
So

```
sdl::fs
```

should set your application in fullscreen mode.

See the manual for more information:

http://grx.gnu.de/grx248um.html#Setting-the-graphics-driver

Comment: Yep, I know about sdl, but that doesn't help. It just expands the window, but still inside a window

Comment: I'm testing the default in ubuntu (gnome?)